Bootstrap 5: How to make printing look the same as in browser
I use bootstrap 5 for my Jsonresume. The design in HTML looks fine, now I want to make the print version look the same (colors, etc.).
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Resume of {{basics.name}}</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous" media='all'>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/30ebcf4eef.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    {{{css}}}
    </style>
  </head>

The custom css does not have any @print, still when I look at the print version, certain elements are not shown or background colors are missing.

dose this post helps you

Check your print settings. Are backgrounds disabled?

Yes backgrounds were not enabled. I enabled it in the print dialog. Thanks A. H.

As pointed out by A Haworth, one only has to enable the "print background" in the printer dialog.

